# It's already 20 minutes into the show

Tags: word-usage

This question's about the use of "into" here. Actually it's 8:20 pm and my favourite program would have started at 8:00pm. I know it's not natural to say:

Two minutes of my show's over.( Well, someone told me.)

But is the use of:
It's 20 minutes already into the show.
Natural?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's 20 minutes already into the show

I would move the word already so

> It's already 20 minutes into the show

or

> It's 20 minutes into the show already

**20 minutes into the show** is really a single unit of speech. Imagine replacing that with Tuesday afternoon. you wouldn't consider saying

> it's Tuesday already afternoon

you would say

> it's Tuesday afternoon already!

or

> it's already Tuesday afternoon!

---

In the comments I was asked if this was a natural wording, and I would say yes it is I can fully imagine somebody saying it. I presume the person is speaking American English as in the UK things on the telly are called "programs" not "shows".

But honestly if I was talking to somebody about it I would say thing like:

> We are already 20 mins in
>
> We have missed 20 mins already

But I have been told I am a terrible communicator in everyday life

---

to expand upon the statement above "We are already 20 mins in" to expand this utterance into a sentence I would write formally:
"Oh No the show started 20 minutes ago, we have missed so much of it.".

"We are" means that we have now been watching this for 20 mins.

Comment: So the use of "into" is natural right,after a few alterations (as suggested by you). I mean ,would you use it?

Comment: I personally haven't used it, but it isn't an unnatural phrase.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish I have included what I would say "I would say thing like:"

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't read that! But what does "in" mean in your sentence? "We are already 20 min in."

Comment: In is shorthand for "into the show"

Comment: What do you use "we" in the sentence "we are already 20 min in"? I mean ,should it be the time that's into the show and not we? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: oh dear, please see more edits